# Changing JS variable with Grunt for different environments

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs, environment-variables

I'm trying to configure my JS build to do next:

I'm using a JS variable to define the application root:

**globals.js**

```
define(function (require) {
   "use strict";
   return {
      mainRoot: "http://myapp.com"
      //mainRoot: "http://localhost:3000" - local run
      //mainRoot: "http://myapp-test.com" - test server
   };
});
```

During local development I'm using code without Grunt build and running Grunt only for test & production builds.

Grunt is running from the Maven plugin using command-line configuration. So it is the only way to pass the environment variable.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.allegro</groupId>
    <artifactId>grunt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <gruntOptions>
            <gruntOption>--verbose</gruntOption>
        </gruntOptions>
        <target>build</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Grunt configuration is pretty simple and looks like this:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'karma',
    'requirejs',
    'concat',
    'csso',
    'copy',
    'processhtml'
]);
```

**The question:**

How can I configure Grunt to change my variable in next way?

1. Default value of `mainRoot` should be `http://localhost:3000`
2. Environment variable should be set via command-line from the Maven plugin
3. When running Grunt with `PROD` environment - `mainRoot` should be changed to  `http://myapp.com`
4. When running Grunt with `TEST` environment - `mainRoot` should be changed to  `http://myapp-test.com`

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using a plugin like [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace)?

Comment: Yes, but it is not clear for me how to setup it with `grunt-env` or similar environment plugins.

Comment: Frankly, there are countless of ways to do this - show us what you tried with grunt-env then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find a combination of [`grunt-replace`](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) and [`grunt-config`](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-config) works well.

In your `Gruntfile.js`, configure `grunt-config` like this (see the [README](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-config#environment-variable-in-source-with-grunt-replace)):

```
config: {
    local: {
        options: {
            variables: {
                mainroot: 'http://localhost:3000'
            }
        }
    },
    test: {
        options: {
            variables: {
                mainroot: 'http://myapp-test.com'
            }
        }
    },
    prod: {
        options: {
            variables: {
                mainroot: 'http://myapp.com'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your `globals.js`, create [an `@@` placeholder](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace#patternsmatch) for `grunt-replace` to find and replace:

```
define(function (require) {
   "use strict";
   return {
      mainRoot: "@@MAINROOT"
   };
});
```

In your `Gruntfile.js`, configure `grunt-replace` like this:

```
replace: {
    my_target: {
        options: {
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: 'MAINROOT',
                    replacement: '<%= grunt.config.get("mainroot") %>'
                }
            ]
        },
        src: ... ,
        dest: ...
    }
}
```

Then create a [command-line option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) such as `--env`, which will accept `local` or `test` or `prod`, and will default to `local` if omitted:

```
var envTarget = grunt.option('env') || 'local';
```

and update your `build` task to use `config` and `replace`:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'config:' + envTarget,
    'replace',
    'karma',
    'requirejs',
    'concat',
    'csso',
    'copy',
    'processhtml'
]);
```

Now you can run Grunt from the command-line with the new `--env` option:

```
grunt build --env=local
grunt build --env=test
grunt build --env=prod
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer! Is it possible to read the environment variables from a .env file instead of explicitly putting them in the gruntifle? Thansk again!